# How to Display Word File On Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Microsoft word Document Contains more than 50 pages

I am creating Mobile app using Xamarin.Forms

how to display the content of word file on One Page(Activity) or any other soultion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no intrinsic way to show a Word Document in a Forms project as on each platform it needs a different solution.

On iOS you can write a custom renderer and use the QLPreviewController, on Android you will need to search for a custom component which will be able to display it and write the custom renderer for it.

Comment: my word file able to convert to text file MyFile.txt .. is there away to Display text file on  xamarin.forms working fine on all platform ..

Comment: Yes, of course, just load the file as an string and then set it as the Text of an Entry or a Label

Comment: You can't access to it from a PCL library, you have two options, create a dependency service and implement the file read on the iOS/Droid package or use the PCL storage package provided by xamarin: https://components.xamarin.com/view/pclstorage

Comment: also right i am trying :   output.Text = DependencyService.Get<ISaveAndLoad>().LoadText("temp.txt"); but i can not find ISaveAndLoad

Answer (score 2):

One solution that my team have had some success with is Syncfusion's Word control,

[Syncfusion Xamarin Products](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin)

Since the release of Visual Studio 2015 Community Editon, Syncfusion have offered a community edition of their product. Depending on the size of your team and their willingness to integrate controls from 3rd party vendors, this may be a good solution for you.